# SlickGrid selection issues on sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, datagrid, selection, slickgrid

When using SlickGrids `selection` and `sorting` together I found that the selection is storing the index of the selected rows rather than storing the selection for the data you selected.

How can I fix this so that the selected data is remembered instead of just an index?

---

A demo of the issue can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/LKf6j/

> To reproduce the issue take the following steps;
>
> 1. Select the first item in the grid
> 2. Sort on name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true)`.

See
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#synchronizing-selection--cell-css-styles

Answer (score 3):

After digging through a few more of the examples I found [this](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) example.

I soon realised to do what I want to achieve I needed to use the `Slick.Data.DataView` APi with the following code.

```
                dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
                    grid.render();
                });



                // initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
                dataView.beginUpdate();
                dataView.setItems(files);
                dataView.endUpdate();

                dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true);
```